# Java Script to get 10% data rows of each employee in google sheets API

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do you get a random sample of 10% of the total entries of each unique employee?

This will be used to get a random sample for auditing.

Comment: Thank you for your exceptionally carefully constructed question, extensive samples of your source data and examples of desired results etc. I'm sure here is a plenty guys that would love to help you in no time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understood correctly, you'd want to get 10% of the entries per employee for random sampling to audit. Then the below approach should be good in your case.

#### Code:

```
function getTenPercent() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // range (including header)
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:C31");
  // get values of the range
  var values = range.getValues();
  // separate header
  var headers = values.shift();
  // variable to modify where your employee name is stored. 0-indexing
  var nameColumn = 0;
  // get unique names (excluding blank cells)
  var uniqueNames = values.map(row => row[nameColumn]).filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i).filter(String);
  // in the data we are going to return, already include the header as the first row
  var data = [headers];

  // for each unique name, we process per name
  uniqueNames.forEach(function (name) {
    // filter our whole data range containing only the current name
    var nameEntries = values.filter(row => row[nameColumn] == name);
    // get its length and get the 10% of it 
    // (using floor so if there are 19 rows, 10% is 1 row)
    var entries = nameEntries.length;
    var tenth = Math.floor(entries / 10);
    // until we get the 10%, loop to get a random row matching the unique name
    for(i=0; i<tenth; i++) {
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * nameEntries.length);
      data.push(nameEntries[random]);
      // remove the already picked item from the current list to avoid duplicates
      nameEntries.splice(random, 1);
    }
  });
  // return data
  return data;
}
```

#### Sample Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- You need to adjust the range based on your data
- You need to adjust where the names are stored. In my sample, I used `0` for the `nameColumn` as the employee name is in my first column. If yours is in another column, then change it.
- Note that this is `0-indexing`. So if your column is in the 2nd column, just subtract 1 and store it in the variable `nameColumn`. It should look like this if your employee name is in 2nd column:

  - `var nameColumn = 1;`
- Data doesn't need to be sorted out like in the sample one.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked and was pretty accurate.

Comment: Hi @SaadatK, If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Can you tell how can I edit the sampling percentage for eg - If i want the 12-13% of samples in this code. I tried doing this but by replacing 10 by 12 & 13 but the sample keeps getting shorter.

Comment: @SaadatK. 100 / 10 is 10%. but 100 / 12 or 13 is not 12/13% respectively. try instead of `var tenth = Math.floor(entries / 10);`, have it `var tenth = Math.floor(entries / 100 * 12);` or `var tenth = Math.floor(entries / 100 * 13);`.

Comment: Hi @NaziA , one issue I am having currently that - if an agent does 19 work the script only picks ups 1 sample can you help me what to do like if I want after 15 work it should pick 2 samples

Comment: Hi @5aadat, you need to post it as another question. This already deviates from the original question I answered. Here in stackoverflow, we do discourage a post that revolves around multiple questions. And also, by posting it in another question, other users can also check your issue which can possibly  provide you a more timely answer. Adding to that, the post is already closed.